# Setting PS1 color

Tags: linux, zsh, colors, prompt

I'd like to color my `zsh` prompt. To do that, I use the following code:

```
export PS1=%F{blue}%n%#
```

but to have it right, I have to add `%f` to the `PS1` value like so:

```
export PS1=%F{blue}%n%#%f
```

When omitting the `%f`, the behavior is strange -- not only does the color affect the prompt, but when I type for e.g. `ls -l`, the first line of its output is also coloured:
[image]

How does setting the `PS1` color value affect other commands? Shouldn't it concern ONLY the prompt?

Answer (score 7):

The `%f` tells the `zsh` shell to stop using the indicated foreground color. The [`zsh` man page on prompt expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Visual-effects) says:

> `%F` (`%f`)
>
> Start (stop) using a different foreground colour, if supported by the terminal.

If you don't tell `zsh` to reset the foreground color, then the subsequent foreground characters get that color, until a new foreground color is specified (e.g. plain files in green).

Answer (score 4):

There are terminal commands to switch to one colour. This is maintained. You would then switch back afterwards.  This can be done with Esc codes directly in the terminal or your special `zsh` specific commands.

```
echo \\033[31m red \\033[34m blue \\033[m and black again
```

(the number of backslashes needed may depend on your shell)

`zsh` interprets the %F and %f and converts them to Esc codes like those above, depending on the terminal.

Comment: This gives `zsh: bad pattern: \033[31m`. `[` is a glob operator and needs quoted in zsh.

Comment: Either `echo` will expand escape sequences like `\033` in which case you'll need two backslashes outside of quotes or one inside single quotes (one or two in double quotes or `$'...'`) or it won't and no amount of backslashes will make a difference (unless you use `$'...'` inside which sequences like `\033` are expanded).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I do these things in shell startup scripts, sometimes even inside the definition of an alias which means I have plenty of more backslashes in my context. Just wanted to make sure where to start if there is a problem.